# jQuery - What is a Tween object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have come across this term for quite a few times, but I can't find detailed definition about it.
For example, parameter `fx` in some jQuery methods is `Tween.init`.

Can anyone offer some help ?

Comment: It looks like the lack of documentation for the `Tween` type was raised a few months ago in an issue here: https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/391 .
Interested parties can feel free to subscribe to notifications for the issue on GitHub.

Comment: jQuery's `Types` page still doesn't document `Tween`, though the documentation for `animate` links to http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Tween

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tween is used in [animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#Tween) in JQuery. [Tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/) being a standalone example of Tween.

> Short for in-betweening, the process of generating intermediate frames
>   between two images to give the appearance that the first image evolves
>   smoothly into the second image. Tweening is a key process in all types
>   of animation, including computer animation. Sophisticated animation
>   software enables you to identify specific objects in an image and
>   define how they should move and change during the tweening process.

From http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/T/tweening.html

Comment: What's your basis for saying that Tween.js is the basis for jQuery's tweening code?  They don't look at all the same.

Comment: Apologies, wrote some of that sentence before changing the content. Updated.

Answer (score 11):

The objects and methods used around jQuery animations - tweens, tweeners, hooks, prefilters, etc - are *very* poorly documented, even though they appear to be part of the public API. Perhaps it helps to list some resources here.

- There is a little bit of info in a [presentation on jQuery animation (slides)](http://gnarf.net/talk-animate/), by Corey Frang, a memeber of the jQuery team. Just two terse slides, actually. Jump in [right here](http://gnarf.net/talk-animate/#extending-hooks).
- There is much more detail in the [draft documentation for jQuery 1.8 Effects](https://gist.github.com/gnarf/54829d408993526fe475), published by the same guy. This is actually the single most helpful resource on the topic I was able to find.

This is what the draft documentation has to say about the properties and methods of the Tween object:

> - `elem`: The element being animated
> - `prop`: The property being animated
> - `easing`: The easing used
> - `options`: A reference to the animation options
> - `start`: The starting value of the tween
> - `now`: The current value of the tween
> - `end`: The ending value of the tween
> - `unit`: The CSS unit for the tween
> - `cur()`: Reads the current value for property from the element
> - `run( progress )`: progress is a number from 0 to 1. Updates the value for the property on the animated element.

A Tween instance is passed to the [`step` callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) of a jQuery animation and can be used to manipulate the animation while it is in progress. Knowing about the Tween API might come in handy there.